# JSON Array Iteration

Tags: arrays, json, iteration

Here is my json output which i am creating from my spring controller.

```
[{"id":"1","name":"albert"},{"id":"2","name":"john"},{"id":"3","name":"mac-millon"},{"id":"4","name":"stenberg"},{"id":"5","name":"almaria"}]
```

In my jsp file ,  am iterating the json array as below

```
success: function(data){
     var content= JSON.parse(data);
     $.each(content, function(i, data) {
                            $('#selectBox').append($('<option>').text(data.name).attr('value',data.id ));
                    });
```

but it always displaying only the last value in my select box

```
id="5" value="almaria"
```

Is there anything wrong in my iteration? or i should create the json output in different format? Please help.

Comment: *"it always displaying only the last value in my select box"* What exactly does that mean? Is there only one `<option>` in the `<select>`? Are the multiple ones but all have the same text/value?   Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: it displays only this:  <option value="5">almaria</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI you should not need to call `JSON.parse` if your headers are set correctly in the response. (Content-Type: application/json).

Your code seems to work fine in this example despite the duplicate IDs.
See that all 5 options appear when the select box is clicked.
There is also the `multiple` HTML attribute which might do what you want.

```js
var content = [{"id":"2","name":"albert"},{"id":"2","name":"john"},{"id":"3","name":"mac-millon"},{"id":"4","name":"stenberg"},{"id":"5","name":"almaria"}];

//var content= JSON.parse(data);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(content, function(i, data) {
     $('#selectBox, #selectBoxMulti').append($('<option>').text(data.name).attr('value',data.id ));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectBox">
</select>

<select id="selectBoxMulti" multiple>
</select>
```

Comment: i tried like this but no luck. Nothing is displaying.   ' data' is returning json values from controller.                                                        :            success: function(data){         
var content = data;
$.each(content, function(i, data) {
     $('#selectBox').append($('<option>').text(data.name).attr('value',data.id));
  });
i am getting this exception :                                                                          Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for.......
              


              
              
             }

Comment: Thanks it works fine. there was some issue in my drop down id.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is your JSON has 2 id: 2
{"id":"2","name":"albert"},{"id":"2","name":"john"}

Not sure if that is the desired logic.